# Google Maps JQuery Code Modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using this script below and it works well except that it is displaying my current location and what I want it to do is to display a specified location instead.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#basic_map').live("pageshow", function() {
$('#map_canvas').gmap('refresh');
});

$('#basic_map').live("pagecreate", function() {
$('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': '52.897699, -1.155959'}).bind('init', function(evt, map) {
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': map.getCenter(), 'animation': google.maps.Animation.DROP }).click(function() {
$('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': 'The Location!'}, this);
});
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the center of the map as variables, something like this,

```
var lat = (...); //Latitude
var lon = (...); //Longitude
...
$('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': lat + ', ' + lon}).bind(...
```

Google Geocoding API can be used to get lat and lon, if needed

Comment: It's still asking me for my Geolocation. I just want it to display the location specified on Lat and Lon with a marker, nothing else.

Comment: Hmm...is your sensor setting set to true or false when initializing the map?  It sounds like it should be set to false in your case...

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#SpecifyingSensor